# Having trouble using Stanford Dogs dataset in TensorFlow importing through tfds.load()

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the Stanford Dogs dataset to practice using image augmentation and create an image classifier. I keep getting errors when I train my model.

I think my problem may have to do with how I resize the image in the normalize function.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras import layers
tfds.disable_progress_bar()

import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

dataset, metadata = tfds.load('stanford_dogs', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
```

```
num_train_examples = metadata.splits['train'].num_examples
num_test_examples = metadata.splits['test'].num_examples
class_names = metadata.features['label'].names

IMG_LEN = 224
N_BREEDS = 120
epochs = 50

image_size = (IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN)
def normalize(image, label):
    normalized_image = tf.image.resize(image, image_size)
    normalized_image /= 255
    return normalized_image, label

batch_size = 32

training_batches = train_dataset.cache().shuffle(num_train_examples//4).batch(batch_size).map(normalize).prefetch(1)
testing_batches = test_dataset.cache().shuffle(num_train_examples//4).batch(batch_size).map(normalize).prefetch(1)

rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape = (IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN,3))
])

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
  layers.RandomZoom(0.1)
])

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])


model.compile(optimizer= "adam",
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=["accuracy"])

from tensorflow.python.distribute.cross_device_ops import validate_destinations
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs = epochs, 
    steps_per_epoch = 1200
)
```

Error:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a35416ceec02> in <module>
     47     train_dataset,
     48     epochs = epochs,
---> 49     steps_per_epoch = 1200
     50 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, None, 3)
```

]

I tried using tf.layers.resizing() in the model but got a similar error about input shape.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised due to the shape mismatch between train_dataset and input shape, which are (None, None, 3) and (224, 224, 3) respectively.
You must first resize the train dataset with the normalize function, and then create the training_batches.

```
train_dataset=train_dataset.map(normalize)
training_batches = train_dataset.cache().shuffle(num_train_examples//4).batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

The training_batches should then be passed to the fit().

```
history = model.fit(
    training_batches,
    epochs = 10, 
    steps_per_epoch = 120
)
```

Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/2039f56dabf5c84ef90c7c81b799e11f/untitled213.ipynb). Thank you!